# how to disable parent window in asp.net using javascript

Tags: asp.net

i hv an asp.net form in which i have used master page, in this by clicking on one link button a popup window will be opened, my problem is i want to close a popup child window when parent form is closed.. or i should make parent form disable when child popup is active...
i got some code but its working only for IE,, please help me to work this in Google chrome
 this is my code which is working For IE
 in parent window i wrote like this

```
function topWindow() {
    var popup = window.open('BranchSearch.aspx', 'mywindow', 'location=1,width=450,height=100,toolbar=0,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,left=340,top=340');
    popup.focus();
        }
```

and in body tag of child pop window i wrote like dis

please help me as soon as possible
thank u

Comment: you can set the parent window opacity level.So that parent window gets highlighted . and pop up window will remain on the top until it is closed

Comment: The body tag in your post isn't displaying - I've tried to edit it but the moderators can't see your original code so think I am adding it in. Try indenting the line four spaces after "i wrote like dis"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **window.showModalDialog** This will disable parent window until you close the child window.